# how to do masking in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have one text box and one submit button. After filling the text box,when we click on submit button,that text box should be masked(we should not able to change anything in text box),not disabled.

```
 <html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            var n = $('#name');
            if (n.attr('readonly')=='readonly') {
                n.removeAttr('readonly');
            } else {
                n.attr('readonly','readonly');
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
       <input type="text" id="name" />
       <button> Lock </button>
</body>
```

i'm doing this by "readonly" attribute, but can we do it by "mask" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can install jquery plugin from http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/ and try like this-

1) http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

2) http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

For example

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

Comment: i didn't get u
i used -
  jQuery(function($){
    $("#yourID").mask("aaa 999");   
   });
but not getting the desired output. and what is the meaning of ("aaa 999")

Comment: @punitjain: just check the links given. you will have better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another input tag, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/ezjz7/) link.
HTML:

```
<input id="name" />
<input id="hiddenName" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" />
<button type="button" onclick="disableInput();">Disable</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function disableInput() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var hiddenName = document.getElementById("hiddenName");
    hiddenName.value = name.value;
    hiddenName.style.display = "inline";
    name.style.display = "none";
}
```